# How can I expose my Azure Table storage data as JSON?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am new to Azure and trying to get the data from Azure table storage. I am able to read it using c# code and do all CRUD operations. But I am looking for built in REST API from azure storage? Is it available?

Below article says that we need to write our own service and deploy.
[https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/09/using-microsoft-azure-table-service-rest-api-to-collect-data-samples](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/09/using-microsoft-azure-table-service-rest-api-to-collect-data-samples/)

But this require me to have IIS ?? or do I have to write app service in c#??

I want JSON because I want to read it from android app but I do not want to use azure android SDK. I want pure REST API

This article http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage is close but it's recommending me create SQL Azure database!! so I am confused.

Comment: Azure Storage provides a REST API for managing tables - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179423.aspx. Is this something that you can use?

Comment: Gaurav, more references appreciated. step by step article !

Comment: Before I do that, I have a quick question for you :). You mentioned that you don't want to use Azure Android SDK. Is there a reason behind this? All the SDKs are essentially a wrapper over REST API so in a way you would be reinventing the wheel. I am curious to know the reason behind this.

Comment: I do not want to store storage key inside android app. When I change them we have to deploy new APK :(  also I have to write new code for iOS. If its REST API I can use in all my mobile platforms.  I am open to discuss best practises and might go to client side coding (SDK) based on direction provided by stack overflow users

Comment: Understood. Not storing storage key inside app is the recommended way to go. Let me include my comments as an answer and see if that approach makes sense in your application.

Comment: why down vote? reason will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I would recommend you go `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` route. In short, a SAS is a `time-limited/permission-based access` to your Azure Storage resources. This removes the need for you to store the storage access key in your application as it poses a major security risk and some other issues.

To read more about SAS, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1. This should give you some idea about what is possible with SAS.

Here's how it would work. There will be a server component which will know about the account key. Your app would request this server component to generate and return the SAS URL. It is recommended that you only grant the necessary permissions and only for the required duration in the SAS.

Once your app has the SAS URL, they can simply make HTTP requests directly to Azure  Storage by using this SAS URL and get the data back directly from Azure Tables in JSON format. For example, if you want to fetch entities from a table you would make `Query Entities` REST API call: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179421.aspx.

To learn more about SAS, please see this link as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx.

Comment: Thanks! Let me dig more on it. How does authorisation work here?

Comment: Authorization for the requests is included in the SAS token as a query string parameter (`sig`). So you don't have to compute authorization header when using SAS.

Comment: The article says that I need to create service in c# code which talks to azure storage and returns JSON data. Is my understanding is right? If so, where will be my service running? do I have to deploy it as web app?

Comment: That's correct. Do you have a backend for your mobile app? If that's the case, then I think you can use that as well instead of creating a service just for this.

Comment: This app is just showing the temperature from a azure storage which is real time pushed by event hub from device to table storage.

Answer (score 1):

> - I do not want to store storage key inside android app.
> - This app is just showing the temperature from a azure storage which is real time pushed by event hub from device to table storage

Regardless your requirement is simply, and it is correct that we don't recommend to expose your storage key in clients. However, to provide table storage entities to your clients, we still need a backend server.

If you have an Azure Mobile Apps server as a backend server for your devices, you can directly integrate Azure Storage SDK in custom APIs to provide table storage entities for your devices. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller for more.

If you don't have an Azure Mobile Apps, you can leverage Auzre Function Apps for you simple requirement, whose environment has automatically added the assembly `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-csharp/ for more.